# How to correctly nest segmentGrop tags in Smooks

Tags: maven, edi, smooks, edifact

I am trying to make EDI to XML mapping with Smooks (1.5 version). I have 5 segments which can occur few times and i want to put them into group but some Error is rising:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'medi:segmentGroup'. 
One of '{"http://www.milyn.org/schema/edi-message-mapping-1.0.xsd":segment}' is expected.
```

My mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<medi:edimap xmlns:medi="http://www.milyn.org/schema/edi-message-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <medi:description name="DVD Order" version="1.0" />

    <medi:delimiters segment="'!$" field="+" component=":" sub-component="~" />
    <medi:segments xmltag="Order">




        <medi:segment segcode="BGM" xmltag="header" >
            <medi:field xmltag="order-id" />
            <medi:field xmltag="status-code" />
            <medi:field xmltag="net-amount" />
        </medi:segment>



        <medi:segment segcode="DTM" xmltag="customer-details">
            <medi:field xmltag="abc" >
                <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                <medi:component xmltag="3"/>      
            </medi:field>
        </medi:segment>
        <medi:segment segcode="NAD" xmltag="customer-details" maxOccurs="-1">
            <medi:field xmltag="asd"></medi:field>
            <medi:field xmltag="abc" >
                <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                <medi:component xmltag="3"/>      
            </medi:field>
        </medi:segment>

        <medi:segment xmltag="CURRENCY" segcode="CUX">
            <medi:field xmltag="1st">
                <medi:component xmltag="nth"/>
                <medi:component xmltag="currency"/>
            </medi:field>
            <medi:field xmltag="number"/>
        </medi:segment>

        **<medi:segmentGroup>**
            <medi:segment xmltag="Linia" segcode="PIA">
                <medi:field xmltag="dig"  />
                <medi:field xmltag="item"/>
                <medi:field xmltag="c">
                    <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="3"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="4"/>
                </medi:field>
            </medi:segment>

            <medi:segment xmltag="Linia2" segcode="PIA">
                <medi:field xmltag="item"/>
                <medi:field xmltag="c">
                    <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="3"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="4"/>
                </medi:field>
            </medi:segment>

            <medi:segment xmltag="prim" segcode="PRI">
                <medi:field xmltag="c">
                    <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="3"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="4"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="5"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="6"/>
                </medi:field>
            </medi:segment>
            <medi:segment xmltag="SCC" segcode="SCC" >
                <medi:field xmltag="1"/>
            </medi:segment>
            <medi:segment xmltag="QTY" segcode="QTY" >
                <medi:field xmltag="qty">
                    <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="3"/>
                </medi:field>
            </medi:segment>
            <medi:segment xmltag="DTM" segcode="DTM">
                <medi:field xmltag="dtm">
                    <medi:component xmltag="1"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="2"/>
                    <medi:component xmltag="3"/>
                </medi:field>
            </medi:segment>
        **</medi:segmentGroup>**
    </medi:segments>
</medi:edimap>
```

I read docs on smooks.org and examples there looks similar. Maybe there is problem with some imports or POM file? Please help me with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with **version** of edi-message-mapping. Version 1.0 doesn't support segmentGroups. There should look like:

```
<medi:edimap xmlns:medi="http://www.milyn.org/schema/edi-message-mapping-1.5.xsd">
```

Comment: are you able to prepare EDI file from XML data?